# Database options for personal code project

Tags: android, .net, sql, database

I am working on developing bank record-keeping software on both windows and android. I would like to use an SQL server to store the data but do not have the resource to run a server at home. The Google drive API provides some functionality, but not at the level I would like. Are there any other suggestions for an online database?

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft's offerings. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: "I would like to use an SQL server to store the data but do not have the resource to run a server at home" - I run one on my desktop.

Comment: go for amazon database

Comment: You don't need a server.  Your can install SQL on a desktop.  SQL Express is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you want to do this app for both windows and android. Note that you can use only sqlite with android, no other database is supported. But you can always use sqlite with windows. What you can do is use sqlite and a syncing service like say dropbox. This will sync your sqlite db with the windows desktop and android.

The other way would be to use hosted database. This could be azure (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/), amazon (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) or you could even use firebase (https://www.firebase.com/)

The third option would be use rent a VPS, (you could get a very cheap one for less than $5 per month) host your own database on it(like mysql, postgresql etc) and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the Dropbox idea. That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There Three options 
a. Windows azure

b. Amazon Simple DB 
http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

c. Zoho Cloud Sql 
https://cloudsql.wiki.zoho.com/